# How can I merge the columns from two tables into one column output

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables with similar information. First Table is suppliers and other table is suppliers_contacts. Is there a way to merge the two columns into one?

My `suppliers` table looks like this:

```
id | contacts_name   | email
-- | ------          | -------
1  | sujith          | sujith@sujith
2  | mark            | 
3  | naveen          | naveen@naveen
```

and `supplier_contacts` table, like this:

```
suppliers_id | name      | email
--           | ----      |
1            | sujith    | sujith1@sujith    
2            | user1     | user1@user1
2            | user2     | user2@user2
3            | naveen1   | naveen1@naveen1
3            | naveen    | naveen2@naveen
```

And I want to get something like this:

```
contacts_name | name      | email 
--            | ------    | ------- 
sujith        | sujith    | sujith@sujith
sujith        | sujith    | sujith1@sujith
user1         | user1     | user1@user1
user2         | user2     | user2@user2
naveen        |           | naveen@naveen
naveen1       | naveen1   | naveen1@naveen1
naveen        | naveen    | naveen2@naveen
```

All the email id should come in one Column from both the tables.

I tried the query below:

```
SELECT
    suppliers.name, 
    supplier_contacts.name AS name1, 
    supplier_contacts.email AS sup_c_email 
FROM suppliers 
JOIN supplier_contacts 
    ON suppliers.id = supplier_contacts.suppliers_id
```

Can anyone help me on this? Basically i want the emails from both the tables to come under one column also should show contacts_name and name from both the tables. If any name or contacts_name is NULL also its fine.

Comment: Please left or right join as per your requirement

Comment: Why does mark not appear in your desired result?

Comment: The email id is null for mark. so could be omitted.

Comment: Fix `FROM supplier` for `FROM suppliers` plural

Comment: Sorry that was a type error. I corrected the question. Basically i want the emails from both the tables to come under one column.

Comment: @Sanju
Can you try using COALESCE(suppliers.email, supplier_contacts.email) in your SELECT ? COALESCE will give you only one non null value

Comment: Yes i tried with COALESCE also, but at times if both the values are there the resultset should show both the emails. How to handle such scenario?

Comment: It should show null in name column for email `sujith@sujith`  in your expected output like `naveen@naveen`

Comment: The resultset am expecting is email list. It should merge the email list from two tables and show in one column.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT suppliers.name, supplier_contacts.name AS name1, supplier_contacts.email AS 
sup_c_email 
FROM supplier 
INNER JOIN suppliers_contacts 
ON suppliers.email = supplier_contacts.email
```

I hope this will help you

Comment: This is the correct answer, if I understood the question correctly.

If not you could do a Left Outer join on the email comparison, to display any results where one email doesn't have a partner.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is a **full outer join**

Although it returns large result-sets.

Great read at this [link](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_full.asp)

Comment: Sadly myssql does not have full outer join.

Comment: Sorry about that. Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4796872/how-to-do-a-full-outer-join-in-mysql). It seems you can emulate them.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT s.contacts_name , sc.name , sc.email
 FROM supplier as s 
 JOIN suppliers_contacts as sc 
 ON s.id = sc.suppliers_id

For more explainations visit below link hope you get help from it 
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-using-joins.htm

Comment: Both the tables have email id fields. It should come in one column.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `union` for your case, first get list of all emails the then do a left join 
with `suppliers_contacts`

```
select
  t.contacts_name,
  s.name,
  t.email
from (
  select contacts_name, email from suppliers where email is not null
  union
  select name, email from suppliers_contacts
) t
left join suppliers_contacts s on t.email = s.email 
order by t.contacts_name;
```

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/87c896/16)

As per your last comment *The resultset am expecting is email list. It should merge the email list from two tables and show in one column*, you can simply use `union` query

```
select contacts_name, email from suppliers where email is not null
union
select name contacts_name, email from suppliers_contacts
order by contacts_name;
```

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/87c896/17)

**Edit** * I want to show all the email address from both the tables with the contacts_name and name from each table. If names are NULL its fine*

```
select
t.contacts_name,
sc.name supplier_contact_name,
s.contacts_name supplier_name,
t.email
from (
  select contacts_name, email from suppliers where email is not null
  union
  select name, email from suppliers_contacts
) t
left join suppliers_contacts sc on t.email = sc.email 
left join suppliers s on t.email = s.email 
order by t.contacts_name;
```

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/87c896/23)

Comment: The union query is working fine. I just wanna know how will i display contact_name field from the suppliers table along with the said fields

Comment: @Sanju can you edit your question and add desired result set ?

Comment: Yes its mentioned in the question. I want to show all the email address from both the tables with the contacts_name and name from each table. If names are NULL its fine.

Comment: @Sanju see last query in my answer

Comment: Actually when am running this query the screen is hanging, so i guess there is some problem. So am trying with the second query a simple Union where i can show the names from both the tables. Thank you @Khalid